# How can I get python to remember an input by a certain name?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python, and am in the process of making a virtual diary project. I have reached a point where if the user asks to write an entry, the date and "Dear Diary" are printed, and they can input an entry. If I want to be able to save this entry, and access it at any point later - amongst other entries - how can I?
**I.e. after I wrote an entry, I would be asked whether to save it. If i chose to, I would then be able to read that specific entry OR another entry I typed next time I  logged on to the virtual diary. The code:**

```
if readOrWrite=="Write":
        print(x.year)
        print(x.month)
        print(x.strftime("%A"))
        writtenText=input("Dear Diary, ")
```

Comment: I do not think that Unix/Linux is the correct part of StackOverflow to ask your Python question. Nevertheless, you might want to have a look at python possibilities for writing .ini, .json or other simple structured files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make use of **file writing and reading** functionality in python. With this you could save the entry and the date it was written on in a file and access it later by searching via the date of the entry. You can look at this [link](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) here for more details.